# Is there a mantained alternative Chrome Stylist?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, css

[Chrome Stylist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylist/pabfempgigicdjjlccdgnbmeggkbjdhd/reviews?hl=en) apparently is no longer mantained, is there a working alternative under active development?

I.e. an extension which allows you to define some specific changes to some specific web pages or domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) allows you to change specific/entire parts of web pages & domains

> Stylebot allows you to quickly manipulate the appearance of any
>   website (using custom CSS).
>
> You pick an element and choose any changes you want to make from the
>   editor. You can change the font size, color, margins, visibility and a
>   lot more. The advanced users can also write the CSS manually.

[image]